# URL validation using using regex giving error

Tags: regex, validation, url, using

```
class Testimmutablestring1{

    public static void main(String[] args )
    {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(http://|https://)?(www.)([a-zA-Z0-9]+).[a- zA-Z0-9]*.[a-z]{3}.?([a-z]+)?$"));
        Matcher m;
        m=p.matcher(https://test.com:8080/wh-101);
    }
}
```

> Error:tablestring1.java:3: error: ';' expected
>   A-Z0-9]+).[a-zA-Z0-9]*.[a-z]{3}.?([a-z]+)?$"));
>   ^
>   tablestring1.java:5: error: ')' expected
>   m=p.matcher(https://test.com:8080/wh-101);
>   ^
>   2 errors

Can anyone please explain

Comment: You have not defined the string literal correctly in `m=p.matcher(https://test.com:8080/wh-101);`. Use `m=p.matcher("https://test.com:8080/wh-101");`

Comment: The first error is because you have a _space_ in the class in the wrong spot. `[a-<space>z`. _a_ is the first character, then the range operator _-_, then a <space>. If you look on an ascii chart, space comes _before_ `a`, thus the range operator error. Just delete the space and that error will vanish.